# Friendly URLS with nginx

Tags: .htaccess, url, nginx

Okay, i have a setup in apache now

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico$

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

i have urls like http://addr.tld/index.php/site and it works fine with apache.

I tried to reproduce it in nginx

```
   root   /home/maciekmm/www;
   index  index.php;

   location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

   location ~ .php$ {
     try_files $uri =404;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     include fastcgi_params;
   }
```

but i get

> rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.php//index.php//index.php//index.php//index.php//index.php//index.php//index.php//index.php//index.php//index.php//about-me"

How should i do it so it redirects urls like it's doing it in apache?

I have a php router beside it, but for testing i disabled redirecting, so it's only printing target.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
root   /home/maciekmm/www;
index  index.php;

location / {     try_files $uri =404;

  try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
}

location @php {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php$1;
}

location ~ "\.php(/|$)" {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```